# AlertDialog.show silently ignored within a service

Tags: android, multithreading, service, dialog

I have a service running a background thread. What I'd like to do is to 
show an AlertDialog initiated from my background thread. I know that 
this is not the recommended way of notifying the user and that it 
interrupts the workflow (as they can pop-up in any application at any 
time) but it's a suitable way for my use case.

There is a handler registered with the background thread and showing a 
Toast notification withing the handler works fine. But after switching 
to an AlertDialog nothing happens anymore. My showDialog logic is 
silently ignored. No Dialog window appears, no log entry. It's a bit 
strange as I'd expect at least a log entry saying that I'm doing 
something wrong or whatever.

Are there any limitations for showing an AlertDialog initiated from a 
service background thread? Some people seem to recommend a Dialog themed 
Activity to get a similar behavior.

Any clarification or help making it work is greatly appreciated!

Yves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to open a dialog from a background thread. The trick is to start an activity which looks like a dialog:

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="YourDialog" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"/>
```

Then, to start your activity:

```
Intent dialog = new Intent(this, YourDialog.class);
dialog.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(dialog);
```

Note that this is asyncrhonous and doesn't block. If you want to process the result, you'll have to use startService() and pass a custom activity to indicate a result.

Emmanuel

Comment: That seems to do the trick. Apparently it's also possible to have an activity that shows an AlertDialog in the onCreate method. The only problem is that we need to start a new task which means we have new activity stack and finishing the dialog with DialogActivity.this.finish() does not navigate back to my last task. Is there any known workaround to get this behavior?

Comment: What's wrong with my approach? When you exit it would go back no?

Comment: Your approach is completely fine. My application bundles the service and a controller activity to start/stop it. For example I start the service through the controller activity, navigate to the browser, then a AlertDialog pops up. So far so good. Now when closing the dialog (DialogActivity.this.finish();) I would expect to get back to the browser but the controller activity appears instead. The solution here is to mark the activity in the manifest with the android:taskAffinity="" attribute to make it completely independent from the controller activity and to get my own empty stack.

Comment: Ok now I understand. (Don't forget to checkmark the best answer.)

Comment: Thank you for the example, I am a newbie in android development so can you please provide a source code for the example submitted by Emmanuel please.

Comment: Thank you for the example, I am a newbie in android development so can you please provide a source code for the example submitted by Emmanuel please.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any limitations for showing an AlertDialog initiated from a service background thread?

The limitation is: it's not possible, AFAIK. You have to show dialogs from the main application thread, not just some arbitrary thread on which you have a `Handler`.

> Some people seem to recommend a Dialog themed Activity to get a similar behavior.

That would seem to be the most likely solution, AFAICT.

Comment: My handler is defined in the main activity of the service class and gets the 'create Dialog' messsage from the background thread. I though this is the way to make sure that I'm on the main application thread?

Answer (score 1):

Another trick is to stay with the AlertDialog but with an additional window type `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Title")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure?")
                    .create();

alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
alertDialog.show();
```

But don't forget to add this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```