# Android - not an enclosing class

Tags: java, android

I knew this question has been asked but I couldn't solve it. I want to show simple AlertDialog on Android's Service. I can show it nicely on MainActivity but I had a problem on Service , Here is my code:

**CustomMainActivity.java:**

```
public void popupDialogMain()
{
    final Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Handler h1 = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
    h1.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mBXmpp)
                mBXmppService.popupDialogMain2();
        }
    });
}
```

**XmppService.java:**

```
public static void popupDialogMain2()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CustomMainActivity.this)
           .setMessage("Look at this dialog!")
           .setCancelable(true)
           .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //do things
               }
           });
     AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
     builder.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
     alert.show();
}
```

I get an error on this line:
**AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CustomMainActivity.this)**

**Android Manifest:** 
I added this permission:

```
android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
```

And I get this error:
**not an enclosing class: CustomMainActivity**

Any suggestion to solve it?

Comment: It's not a good practice to display the alert from a service.!! Try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19269931/4596556)

Comment: *"I knew this question has been asked but I couldn't solve it."* Link to the previous questions/answers you read and couldn't apply to your code, and to the extent possible, say *why* you couldn't apply them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is not an enclosing class Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252727/is-not-an-enclosing-class-java)

Comment: Pass the data from service to activity thorough intent/local broadcast. In the receiving end alert the data!.

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar I use a link that you sent but I get an error yet.

Comment: @afn for alert dialog there should be an activity running. Without the activity you can't do anything. But you can start the activity looks like dialog [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4135248/4596556)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access a `this` from a static method.

Comment: You could pass the `Context` as a parameter to `popupDialogMain2()`